Laravel Html Checkbox Array Posting Empty Values and Retaining Upon Form Submission Error
I have the following form inputs in a laravel 10 application using spatie html:
  @foreach ($roles as $role)

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            {{-- Hidden field to ensure unchecked checkboxes are recognized --}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_roles[]" value="" id="hidden_{{ $role->name }}">
                            {{ html()->checkbox('user_roles[]')->value($role->id)->checked(in_array($role->id, old('user_roles[]', $user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray())))->id($role->name) }} {{ $role->label }}
        
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

There is a hidden checkbox to ensure unchecked checkboxes are posted for any form validation. When I post the form without checking any checkboxes,the hidden checkbox array will still get posted with a null value so it isn't exactly empty
"user_roles" => array:1 [▼
  0 => null
]

Ideally I would want to post the hidden field as an empty array so that in the form request it appears as an empty array which obviously isn't possible:
"user_roles" => array:1 []
Basically I want the form in edit mode on initial load to pre check any saved user roles. If the user then uncheck/checks different roles and on form submission error and I want to preserve those selections. currently if i uncheck all the checkboxes and post the form the validation rule is getting bypassed
$rules = [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . ($this->isUpdate ? $this->id : '' ),
        'password' => [$this->isUpdate ? 'nullable' : 'required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)->letters()->numbers()->uncompromised()],
        'user_roles' => [
            'required',
            'array',
            'min:1'
        ],
        


    ];

I've tried setting different values to the hidden field to no avail e.g. non of the following work - they all add an initial item to the array
<input type="hidden" name="user_roles[]" value="0" id="hidden_{{ $role->name }}">

<input type="hidden" name="user_roles[]" id="hidden_{{ $role->name }}">

If I dont add a hidden field and I submit the form without selecting any roles then a form submission error occur but if I'm in edit mode then the checkboxes prepopulate with the previous database saved values as opposed to the old values
This was all working fine in Laravel collective but struggling to get it to work with spatie html.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].
